# Calculate the mean each day based on per minute data with differing lengths of per min. data

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, mean

I have two arrays, date and temp. I wish to calculate the mean temperature per day. There are minutely observations, it is not as simple as looping and averaging every 1,440 values. The sensor turns on to record the temperature at random times. A day can have 8 minutes of observations or 1,440. Therefore I will have to iterate through each day.

**Data**:
Two equal length Numpy arrays:

```
dates = ['2017-10-24 06:18:00.000' '2017-10-24 06:19:00.000' '2017-10-24 06:20:00.000' ... '2018-11-23 16:56:00.000' '2018-11-23 16:57:00.000' '2018-11-23 16:58:00.000']
temp = [1 2 3 ... 5 2 9]
```

I figure I need to select out the 'day' value in dates and iterate through that by +1 day

Pseudo code:

```
AmountOfDays = max(dates.%d)-min(dates.%d)
day_index = 0
for i in days:
    for j in AmountOfDays
        np.mean(temp)
```

Comment: Do you want not to use pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.array(dates, dtype=np.datetime64), 'temp': temp})
df.groupby(df.date.dt.date)['temp'].mean()
```

Comment: I don’t not want to the rest of the code doesn’t utilize pandas but I’ll try to implement this. Cheers. @josemz